# List being cleared When go back to index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a database model that I am using for a List within a class however  I am calling it as a singelton from my controller but when the model gets retrieved its empty again. I persume its becasue i am going to the pages location again.

```
public class ElectricianController : Controller {
    private IDatabaseService ds;
    public IActionResult Index(ElectricianModel model) {           
        return View(ds.GetAllCircuits());
    }
```

Its at this point above the GetAllCircuits is where the list is cleared again ?

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveCircuit(CircuitModel model) {             
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
  //it wants to be a new record their for add to it 
   if (model.Id > 0) {
      ViewBag.Title = "Update";
      ds.UpdateCircuit(model);
    } else {
      ViewBag.Title = "Create";
      ds.AddToCircuits(model);
   }
        var query = ds.GetAllCircuits();
    }
 }
```

This is my service here.

```
 public class ElectricalSurveyDL : IDatabaseService {
    public  ApplicationDBContext db;
    public List<CircuitModel> CircuitsList;
    public ElectricalSurveyDL(ApplicationDBContext dbcontext) {
        db = dbcontext;
        if(CircuitsList == null)
        CircuitsList =  new List<CircuitModel>();
 } 

 public void AddToCircuits(CircuitModel model) {
     CircuitsList.Add(model);            
 }
 public List<CircuitModel> GetAllCircuits() {
     return CircuitsList.ToList();
 }
```

Its adds the circuit fine but when it gets back to the page it has destroyed it again.
I am adding my layer in as follows in startup.cs

```
  services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService, ElectricalSurveyDL>();
```

Should the way i done the list not mean it lasts through out the application and not just the page?

**> Edit 2**

I changed to the following but now get this error.
     services.AddSingleton();

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
>   the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
>   ElectricalSurvey.DAL.IDatabaseService Lifetime: Singleton
>   ImplementationType: ElectricalSurvey.DAL.ElectricalSurveyDL': Cannot
>   consume scoped service 'ElectricalSurvey.DAL.ApplicationDBContext'
>   from singleton 'ElectricalSurvey.DAL.IDatabaseService'.)'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService, ElectricalSurveyDL>();
```

Each new request creates new instance of ElectricalSurveyDL therefor the List CircuitsList is being initialized in ElectricalSurveyDL`s constructor as new List because expression:

```
 if (CircuitsList == null)
                    CircuitsList = new List<CircuitModel>()
```

in current registration is always true

If you want to keep it as singleton use:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService, ElectricalSurveyDL>()
```

Comment: Please see edit 2 am getting an error on startup if I change it to Singleton.